# Doctrine ORM schema-tool:update Error: Call to a member function add() on boolean

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm encountering this error when trying to update my database via the CLI:

```
> vendor\bin\doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql
Error: Call to a member function add() on boolean in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\jobrouter\_projects\event-app\bootstrap.php on line 10

Call Stack:
0.0013     352656   1. {main}() C:\...\vendor\doctrine\orm\bin\doctrine:0
0.0028     353432   2. include('C:\...\vendor\doctrine\orm\bin\doctrine.php') C:\...\vendor\doctrine\orm\bin\doctrine:4
0.0078     362368   3. require('C:\...\cli-config.php') C:\...\vendor\doctrine\orm\bin\doctrine.php:48
0.0082     362752   4. require_once('C:\...\bootstrap.php') C:\...\cli-config.php:3
```

This is my bootstrap.php:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$autoloader = require_once __DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php";
$autoloader->add('', __DIR__."/src/library/");


// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), 
$isDevMode, null, null, false);

// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => '...',
    'password' => '...',
    'host' => '...',
    'dbname' => '...',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
);

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

This is my composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
    "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "2.*",
    "silex/silex": "~2.0",
    "j7mbo/twitter-api-php": "^1.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true
  }
}
```

I have no problems using the app in the browser, autoloading works as intended. I only get this error when trying to use the Doctrine CLI and don't understand how `$autoloader` can possibly be a boolean when it should always return an object.

Has someone encountered a similar error and how did you fix it?

Edit: I have just ran my app through the debugger and `require_once __DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php";` returns the correct object for `$autoloader` and not a bool. I'm completely lost here.

Comment: How about sharing `bootstrap.php` so we can do more than just a wild guess?

Comment: @localheinz Part of it was already in my post but I have edited and put the full `bootstrap.php` in it.

Comment: Can you also share your `composer.json`?

Comment: @localheinz Done. Also added an additional edit. I'm even more confused than before now.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have already configured PSR-0 autoloading

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "library/src/"
        }
    }
}
```

there is no need for

```
$autoloader = require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$autoloader->add(
    '', 
    __DIR__ . '/src/library/'
);
```

Adjust `boostrap.php` to require the autoloader only:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

then make sure that `vendor/autoload.php` exists, ideally by running

```
$ composer install
```

or

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

in the root of the project.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve my problem, I kept getting more and more (different) errors all the way down, looks like I botched my ORM somehow. I ended up updating the database manually. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, at least my autoloader is a lot more elegant now :D